# Symfony console language changed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to learn Symfony framework.

When I type bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load command my console language changes to Japanese (I think) and as a result I can not debug my error.  Can anyone please help make Symfony console to print the results in English?

The following is the error I am getting from running the above command.
J�│T␤␋⎽ ⎼␊⎽⎺┤⎼␌␊ °⎺⎼┐ ␋┼├␊┼├␋⎺┼▒┌┌≤ ┌␊°├ ␉┌▒┼┐   ��PHP P▒⎼⎽␊ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼:  ⎽≤┼├▒│ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼, ┤┼␊│⎻␊␌├␊␍ '␊│├␊┼␍' (T_STRING), ␊│⎻␊␌├␋┼± 'π' ␋┼ /⎻⎼⎺┘␊␌├⎽/└▒┴▒/⎽⎼␌/A⎻⎻B┤┼␍┌␊/D▒├▒F␋│├┤⎼␊⎽/ORM/L⎺▒␍P⎼⎺┘␊␌├⎽.⎻␤⎻ ⎺┼ ┌␋┼␊ 9

P▒⎼⎽␊ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼: ⎽≤┼├▒│ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼, ┤┼␊│⎻␊␌├␊␍ '␊│├␊┼␍' (T_STRING), ␊│⎻␊␌├␋┼± 'π' ␋┼ /⎻⎼⎺┘␊␌├⎽/└▒┴▒/⎽⎼␌/A⎻⎻B┤┼␍┌␊/D▒├▒F␋│├┤⎼␊⎽/ORM/L⎺▒␍P⎼⎺┘␊␌├⎽.⎻␤⎻ ⎺┼ ┌␋┼␊ 9

[S≤└°⎺┼≤\C⎺└⎻⎺┼␊┼├\D␊␉┤±\E│␌␊⎻├␋⎺┼\F▒├▒┌E⎼⎼⎺⎼E│␌␊⎻├␋⎺┼]
  P▒⎼⎽␊ E⎼⎼⎺⎼: ⎽≤┼├▒│ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼, ┤┼␊│⎻␊␌├␊␍ '␊│├␊┼␍' (T_STRING), ␊│⎻␊␌├␋┼± 'π'

␍⎺␌├⎼␋┼␊:°␋│├┤⎼␊⎽:┌⎺▒␍ [--°␋│├┤⎼␊⎽ [FIXTURES]] [--▒⎻⎻␊┼␍] [--␊└ EM] [--⎽␤▒⎼␍ SHARD] [--⎻┤⎼±␊-┬␋├␤-├⎼┤┼␌▒├␊] [--└┤┌├␋⎻┌␊-├⎼▒┼⎽▒␌├␋⎺┼⎽] [-␤≠--␤␊┌⎻] [-─≠--─┤␋␊├] [-┴≠┴┴≠┴┴┴≠--┴␊⎼␉⎺⎽␊] [-V≠--┴␊⎼⎽␋⎺┼] [--▒┼⎽␋] [--┼⎺-▒┼⎽␋] [-┼≠--┼⎺-␋┼├␊⎼▒␌├␋⎺┼] [-␊≠--␊┼┴ ENV] [--┼⎺-␍␊␉┤±] [--] <␌⎺└└▒┼␍>

Here is framework related settings in my config.xml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

## Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration

parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

Comment: Check your `app/config/config.yml` file for locale information.

Comment: I actually checked that before and the default locale is 'en'.